# How to Append data before saving polygon in Openlayers 2

Tags: wfs, openlayers-2, database

I creat a new polygon but before saving i want to append some data such as polygon name , color etc. How can i do this ?

I am using this function

```
var SaveStrategy: new OpenLayers.Strategy.Save();

this.wfs = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("WFS-T" , {
        strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.BBOX(), this.saveStrategy],
        projection:  new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:3857"),
        protocol:    new OpenLayers.Protocol.WFS({
            version:     "1.1.0",
            srsName:     "EPSG:3857",
            url:         "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wfs",
            featureNS:   "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/mall",
            featureType:  stores,
            geometryName: 'geom'
        })

    });


var save = new OpenLayers.Control.Button({
            title: "Save Changes",
            trigger: function() {
                if(edit.feature) {
                    edit.selectControl.unselectAll();
                }
                Home.saveStrategy.save();
            },
            displayClass: "olControlSaveFeatures"
        });
```

Polygon Table:

```
gid | name    | background | geom
----+---------+------------+------------
1   | Store 1 | #FFFFF     | {geom_data}
```

Comment: What is the question exactly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I found the problem

```
var draw = new OpenLayers.Control.DrawFeature(
        this.wfs, OpenLayers.Handler.Polygon,
        {
            title: "Draw Feature",
            displayClass: "olControlDrawFeaturePolygon",
            multi: false,
            featureAdded: function(object){

             /* Database Column Values Here :) */
                object.attributes = {
                    'background':'#00000',
                    'name':'test'
                }

                console.log(object);
            }
        }

    );
```